# Firebase.auth() is not a function Error REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am trying to implement firebase authentication in my project. However, I'm getting the error Firebase.auth() is not a function. Does anyone know why this is happening?

App.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

js

```
import React from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
export const loginRequest = (email, password) =>
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
```

instead.

or

```
import * as firebase from '@react-native-firebase';
```

You are trying to use the App library for everything. It only works as the App library.

Comment: Unfortunately, both suggestions did not solve the issue. Do you have any ideas why it does not recognise the auth function?
With the implementation of your suggestions, I am getting the same error: firebase.auth is not a function

Comment: yarn add @react-native-firebase/auth

Comment: it does not solve the issue. The issue must be related to imports. However, there is no documentation regarding the matter online